# passing searched from search input to another component to be displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-context

i am really stuck on how i can pass searched data which a user types from my search bar in the header component to the main component to be displayed.

Currently if i place a search bar in my main component, it searches very well and data is displayed but for my case i want to search from the header component.

I have seen some solutions on stack overflow but i have failed to come up with a solution.

Below is what i have tried:

```
//implementing search icon
<Search
  placeholder="Search..."
  allowClear
  size="large"
  style={{
    paddingTop: "14px",
  }}
  onSearch={(value) => {
    setSearchedText(value)
  }}
  searchedText={searchedText}
/>
```

Below is my main component where i want the data to be displayed

```
const Home = (props) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [items, setItems] = useState([])
    const [IsLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        let path = `api/v1/homes?query=${props.searchedText}`
        axios.get(path)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setItems(res.data)
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [searchedText])
```

I have removed some code to make it somehow tidy

Comment: Voted to close for lack of clarity. The post is in a mix of formats that is exceedingly hard to read. The OP should review their post and edit.

Comment: @Chris I just made an edit to OP's post to fix the formatting. Please approve. I think it's a valid question otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be looking for state management libraries like Redux, Recoil, etc.

Recoil is good for beginners since it's easy to learn, https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/getting-started/

or useContext for less library usage. https://dev.to/hey_yogini/usecontext-for-better-state-management-51hi

I really want to write a code for you, but it actually does not help at all.
You should learn on your own :)

Comment: the useContext hook has been exellent. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a common parent component that will keep track of `searchText` and will pass it to the `Home` component to display.

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('')

   return (
      <>
         <Search searchText={searchText} setSearchText={setSearchText} />
         <Home searchText={searchText} />
      </>
   )
}
```

`<Search />` will then use `props.searchText` and `props.setSearchText` and `<Home />` will use `props.searchText`.

[This has to do with the unidirectional dataflow that Reach is based](https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react). There are essentially two main ways a components keeps track of it's data - via `state` and `props`. When either `state` or `props` changes the component re-renders to display new data. `state` can be set from within the component (using `useState` hook for example) and `props` is passed to the component from it's parent. We use can pass callbacks from a parent to its children allow children to update parent's state. This means you cannot pass data directly between siblings, so you need a common parent.

There are other alternatives like `Context` and `Redux`, but they all essentially use the same approach under the hood.

Comment: also a great idea